# Error al añadir un archivo .txt mediante pyinstaller, no me da error al añadirlo pero al ejecutar el 'exe' me dice que el archivo no se encuentra

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

ejecuto pyinstaller de esta forma:

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'mi_archivo.txt;.' mi_archivo.py --noconsole --onefile
```

el archivo mi_archivo.py contiene solo esto:

```
with open('mi_archivo.txt') as f:
    contenido = f.read()
print(contenido)
```

el código funciona correctamente antes de crear el ejecutable.
Cuando creo el ejecutable con pyinstaller no me da ningún error pero al ejecutar my_archivo.exe que ha creado pyinstaller me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mi_archivo.py", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mi_archivo.txt'
```

Para que my_archivo.exe no de error tengo que poner mi_archivo.txt en la misma ruta del ejecutable lo cual sería lógico si no fuera porque le estoy poniendo la opción --onefile precisamente para que el ejecutable ya contenga mi_archivo.txt

Alguien me puede decir qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

he descubierto que las rutas relativas no funcionan porque se relacionan al archivo .exe y no al archivo .py del que pides el archivo. Te recomiendo usar la siguiente función con `__file__` para obtener la carpeta raíz y ahí se debería ubicar todos los archivos que solicites al usar --add-data:

```
def dirname(path:str) -> str: return path.replace("\\", "/").rsplit("/", 1)[0]

#Ruta de la carpeta del archivo:

ROOT_FOLDER_PATH = dirname(__file__)

#Digamos que queremos obtener el archivo de texto:

with open(f"{ROOT_FOLDER_PATH}/archivo.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
print(content)
```